# titleLable.text not working

Tags: ios, uibutton

I create an UIButton and use `titleLable.text` to set text ,but the text is not seen in the button so I replace it with `setText` method, and it show the text, I just want to know why the `titleLable.text` is not working

```
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.titleLabel.text=@"text";
```

Then used like below

```
    [button setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `titleLabel` is a `readonly` property.

> **titleLabel**
>
> A view that displays the value of the `currentTitle` property for a
>   button. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *titleLabel` >
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are
>   read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of
>   the button. For example:
>
> `UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`
>
> `button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];`
>
> `button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;`
>
> **Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and
>   setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those
>   changes.**
>
> **The titleLabel property returns a value even if the button has not
>   been displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system
>   buttons.**
>
> **Availability**
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIButton.h

Please refer [UIButton Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) for more details.

Comment: so you mean the titleLabel property is only for storing a text but not for showing text in the button

Comment: @VigneshKumar: "The reason setting the text does not work is that the button itself will be setting the text internally, depending on the control state. This will override anything you've set as the text."

Answer (score 1):

Midhun's answer, while completely true, doesn't answer the question. As he says, the label property is read-only but *its* properties are not, including the text property.

The reason setting the text does not work is that the button itself will be setting the text internally, depending on the control state. This will override anything you've set as the text.

This is why you use `setTitle:forControlState:` instead. The button will use the value for the normal state for all other states, unless you tell it otherwise, but if you never set a title for any control state, it will not show the label.